# How do I use the like operator in SQL with php user input?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

```
$search_query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['this']);
$sql = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE this LIKE ' '%' + " .$search_query. " + '%' '";
```

This is what I have so far, is there something wrong with this syntax?

Comment: You have misplaced single quotes after `LIKE` and at the end of your statement. Should be: `$sql = "SELECT this FROM that WHERE this LIKE '%' + '" .$search_query. "' + '%' "`.

Comment: But bottom line: **[use prepared statements at all time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**!

Comment: @GMB Maybe im not doing it correctly then, because I can't echo the results.
If I do
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo mb_substr($row["this"]);

Comment: Echoing @GMB **please please please** use prepared statements!  Writing SQL commands like you're doing is **extremely unsafe**.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `+` for string concatenation, it uses the `CONCAT()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rewrite your query using prepared statements you won't have this type of issue. For example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT this FROM that WHERE this LIKE ?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$search_query = '%' . $_POST['this'] . '%';
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search_query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['this'];
}
```

Note [`get_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) is only available with the `mysqlnd` driver, if you don't have that, replace the last 4 lines with

```
$stmt->bind_result($ths);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $ths;
}
```